# Get the spatial reference of an ArcGIS layer with C#

Tags: arcgis-server, coordinate-system, arcgis-silverlight-api

I'm using the following C# code to add my layer dynamically on an ArcGIS silverlight application:

```
ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer mylayer = new ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer()
{
   ID = layerName,
   Url = mapServiceUrl,
 };
 mylayer.Initialize();
 mylayer.Initialized += mylayer _Initialized;
 mylayer.InitializationFailed += mylayer _Failed;
 myMap.Layers.Add(mylayer );
```

But when I try to get the spatial reference of the layer using:

```
SpatialReference sp = mylayer.SpatialReference;
int testww = sp.WKID;
```

I get an error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." because mylayer.SpatialReference is Null.

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the spatial reference of the layer ,Initialized event is useful, i.e. your "mylayer _Initialized" event.Have you tried that?

```
private void MyService_Initialized(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
Layer layer = sender as Layer;

//get spatial reference here...
}
```

Comment: I use mylayer_Initialized only for populating some comboboxes... How can I add to get spatia reference?